# Hosting shinyApp on EC2 with background running capability

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, shiny, markdown

I want to host a shiny app on amazon EC2 which takes a excelsheet using fileinput(). Then I need to make some API calls for each row in the excelsheet which is expected to take 1-2 hours on average for my purposes. So I figured out that this is what I should do:

1. Host a shiny app where one can upload an excelsheet.
2. On receiving an excelsheet from a user, store it on the amazon servers, notify the user that an email will be sent once the processing is complete, and trigger run another R script (I'm not sure how to do that) which will keep running in background even if the user closes the browser window and collect all the information by making the slow API calls.
3. Once I have all the data, store it in another excelsheet and email back to the user.

If it is possible and reasonable to do it this way or you have some other ideas to do my task, please help me with how to do it.

**Edit:** I've found  this is what I can do otherwise:

1. Get the excelsheet data and store it in a file.
2. Call a bash script from the R shiny like this: `./<my-script> &; disown`
3. The bash script will call a python file which makes all API calls, decodes the relevant data from JSON output and stores it in another file on the server.
4. It finally sends an email to the user with he processed data attached.

I wanted to know if this is an appropriate way to do the job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing simple web framework like Django since you are using python. [Flask](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) may come in handy for creating simple routes. Please comment if you find any issues.

Comment: I am actually using Flask right now. Thanks for your help!